run a vba through differents .txt files
I have code that removes quote marks (“) from a txt file but a have a long list of files to run this code.
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String
    Dim FlName As String
        
    '~~> Change this to the relevant text file
    FlName = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\test.txt"
        
    '~~> Open text file in 1 go and read it
    Open FlName For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    
    '~~> Replace double quotes
    MyData = Replace(MyData, Chr(34), "")
        
    '~~> Write back to text file.
    Open FlName For Output As #1
    Print #1, MyData
    Close #1
End Sub

I wish a way that vba open a list of txt files and run the code in every single one of the files without needing to replace the file location
I've tried made a loop referring to a list inside a excel sheet but didn't work and i don't know whats wrong
